# How to set dynamic height to a view inside a scrollView in reactNative

Tags: react-native, scrollview

This is my code:

```
<ScrollView>
  <View>
   <Text1/> 
   <Text2/>
   ... 
  </View>
```

The `ScrollView` only works when the `View` inside has a specific height, but the number of objects inside the view can change, so the height should adjust accordingly. However, I don't know how to do it.

I attempted to calculate the height by multiplying the height of a single text object by the number of objects (they all have the same height), but it seems that the height is not sufficient to activate the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to achieve this behavior is by using the flexGrow property in React Native.

Here is an example using views with dynamic sizes. I added borders and colors for easier visualization.

```html
 <ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{
      flexGrow: 1,
      borderColor: "green",
      borderWidth: 5
    }}
  >
    <View style={{ borderColor: "purple", borderWidth: 5 }}>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{ borderColor: "red", borderWidth: 5 }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>World</Text>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work on my code

Comment: It worked, I just needed to add the Scrollview in a View with a fixed height